# Оптимизация кода создания потоков c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Доброго времени суток, стоит задача : вызвать метод n раз использовав при этом m потоков (нужно, чтоб одновременно). Я тут набросал код

```
while (num < numto)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Get));
        myThread.Start(num);
        num++;
    }
}
```

Где Get

```
static void Get(object x)
{
    try
    {
        int n = (int)x;            
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
    catch (HttpException ex)
    {   
    }
}
```

Если `num = 0` и `numto = 10000`, то `while` закончит работу примерно через 1м и 40с, можно ли как-то оптимизировать код, что бы все запускалось быстрее? Надеюсь, что ясно выразился, если понадобится, то объясню по другому

UPD:
Попытался использовать такую схему

```
sw.Start();

int nWorkerThreads;
int nCompletionThreads;
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out nWorkerThreads, out nCompletionThreads);
Console.WriteLine("Максимальное количество потоков: " + nWorkerThreads
                      + "\nПотоков ввода-вывода доступно: " + nCompletionThreads);

while (num < numto)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Get), num);
        num++;
    }
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine((sw.Elapsed.ToString()));
```

`While` прошел за 0,2 сек. Да и корректен ли данный способ реализации (через пул потоков) для данной задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случай вы создаете очень много потоков, а это дорогая операция, поэтому у вас это занимает почти 2 мин.
Во втором случай вы используете готовые потоки которые уже созданы платформой .NET (пул потоков).

Для болей красивой реализации используёте `Task`

```
while (num < numto)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        Task.Run(() => Get(num));
        num++;
    }
} 

private static void Get(int x)
{
    try
    {
        var n = x;
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
    catch (HttpException ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: ругается System.Threading.Tasks.Task" не содержит определение для "Run

Comment: получается, что я могу использовать все доступные потоки nWorkerThreads ?

Comment: @Lolidze Видемо вы используете NET 4.0. тогда напишите Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Get(num)); 

Да вы можете использовать их все, вы ставити задачу в очередь, а потоки из тред пула начинают их выполнять.